# How can I zoom one single editor group independently from others in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually use the split editor for easier inspection in VS Code. My eyes are not good so the setting `"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true` is already awesome. But sometimes, I need zoom in specific one split editor more others.
Is there any way to do that?

[image: Split Editor]

[image: Zoom By Scroll]

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist at the time of this writing, and was turned down in the past.

From googling "`github vscode issues zoom individual editor group`", I found this feature-request: [Different zoom levels / fontsizes per editor group #80638](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80638), which at the time of this writing is closed as "out of scope" with [this message](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80638#issuecomment-541744096) (emphasis added):

> This issue is being closed to keep the number of issues in our inbox on a manageable level, we are closing issues that are not going to be addressed in the foreseeable future: We look at the number of votes the issue has received and the number of duplicate issues filed. More details [here](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope). **If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.**
>
> If you wonder what we are up to, please see our [roadmap](https://aka.ms/vscoderoadmap) and [issue reporting](https://aka.ms/vscodeissuereporting) guidelines.

Comment: @meo658 you're welcome. feel free to upvote and mark this answer as accepted if you think it is worthy of it.